# How do I keep pagination in a fixed position?

Tags: css, reactjs

I make a task tracker where I can display 4 tasks at a time. When there are more than 4, the following tasks get added to the next page using React pagination.

I would like the page numbers to be in a fixed position and never move. For example, if I have 2 pages of tasks, the first has the full 4 tasks and the second page has 2 tasks, my pagination shifts up and is always right under the last task.

Task component

```
const Task = ({ tasks, setTasks, completeTask, removeTask }) => {
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);

  const tasksPerPage = 4;
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * tasksPerPage;

  const displayTasks = tasks
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + tasksPerPage)
    .map((task, index) => {
      return (
        <div
          className={task.isComplete ? 'todo-row complete' : 'todo-row'}
          key={index}>
          <div key={task.task_id} onClick={() => completeTask(task.task_id)}>
            {task.description}
          </div>
          <div className='icons'>
            <RiCloseCircleLine
              onClick={() => removeTask(task.task_id)}
              className='delete-icon'
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });

  const pageCount = Math.ceil(tasks.length / tasksPerPage);

  const changePage = ({ selected }) => {
    setPageNumber(selected);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {displayTasks}
      <ReactPaginate
        previousLabel={'Back'}
        nextLabel={'Next'}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        onPageChange={changePage}
        containerClassName={'paginationBttns'}
        previousLinkClassName={'previousBttn'}
        nextLinkClassName={'nextBttn'}
        activeClassName={'paginationActive'}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

CSS styling

```
.paginationBttns {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 18px;
  padding-left: 0;
  color: white;
  bottom: 12px;
}

.previousBttn, .nextBttn {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.paginationBttns a {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.paginationBttns a:hover {
  background: #00adb5;
}

.paginationActive a {
  background: #00adb5;
}
```

I made a code sandbox to try and show what's happening. How do I make my pagination stay in a fixed position?

[Task Tracker Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-pine-ff1gg)

Comment: Put the pagination above the elements (or fix the height of the elements). I personally prefer having pagination at the top.

Comment: @Djave That would definitely be an easier fix but at the top I have an input form where I add new tasks so I'm trying to keep it at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to first set a `min-height`to the wrapper style and then use `position:relative` and add a `position:absolute`to the pagination block:
like this:

```
.wrapper {
  background: pink;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.paginationBttns {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  left: 40%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  color: white;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

[image: Edit busy-dust-b58u9]